# What could be excluded from Spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, build

I am using JPA, hibernate, AOP, web, webmvc, context, core, beans.

Not using junit, test etc. at this moment.

What libs I could exclude, how and where is better to
place exclutions?

P.S. Yes, I need this in fat jar or war.

P.P.S. Yes, I need fat jar or war.

Comment: you can exclude from maven pom.xml. Is your question like what you can exclude and still i can run spring boot app?

Comment: You exclude whatever isn't needed. The whole point of having multiple starters is that you pick the pieces that you do need and just don't include the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot starter bundles the required jars so that overhead of adding the required dependencies manually with correct version is eliminated. Example, spring-boot-starter-web integrates all the dependencies required to create a simple web application.
But, if we need to add our own required dependency other that packaged with starters we can exclude using exclusion tag in maven deployment descriptor file(pom.xml).

Example,
If you want to exclude spring-boot-starter-logging and add your own required logging dependency you can do by following way.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For testing you can simply don't use spring-boot-starter-boot-test dependency.